# .htaccess not redirecting to 404 after RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

i'm having an issue with redirecting 404 errors to my 404 page and I'm guessing it has to do with my rewrite rule since when I delete it it works perfectly, but i can't find a fix for this.

I have this .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm rewriting all

```
profile.php?username=name
```

to

```
domain.com/name
```

for pretty urls. That is working fine.

Now my problem is when i have a 404 error. Instead of redirecting to my 404 page it just loads my site without any css, just plain html and on the actual url.

Example: let's say I go to domain.com/name and the username exists, everything loads fine. But, if go to domain.com/name/something it loads plain html instead of going to 404, and I know there's nothing in domain.com/name/something, so it should return a 404.

Is my rewrite rule ok? If anyone could help me out i'd appreciate it!

Comment: so `/404` now is `profile.php?username=404`

Comment: You redirect every URL that does not exist to `profile.php?username=`. It is for you to do the necessary in this page

Comment: Oh ok i see it now. So should i check in profile.php if the user exists and if it doesn't then i redirect to 404? Something like `header("Location: 404")`? Is that the best way to do it? Or is there something "cleaner" i could do on htaccess?

Comment: Yes. I advise to place users in a folder. And then you rewrite only the links in this folder.

Comment: Great, thank you! @Croises